# Excel Macro Graph Removing Blank Legend Keys

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Option Explicit

Public PlotName As String
Public PlotRange As Range

Sub Tester()
Range("TCKWH.V.1").Select
AddPlot ActiveSheet.Range("KWH_G_1")
End Sub


Sub AddPlot(rng As Range)
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
PlotName = .Name
.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rng.Address())
.Chart.HasTitle = True
.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = Range("KWH.G.1")
.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
 .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Range("KWH.G.1")
 End With
Set PlotRange = rng
Application.EnableEvents = False
rng.Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Sub FixPlott(rng As Range)
Dim n As Long
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(PlotName)
  For n = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
  With .SeriesCollection(n)
      If PlotName = "" Then
          .Delete
        End If
      End With
      Next n
    End With
    End Sub
Sub RemovePlot(rng As Range)
 If Not PlotRange Is Nothing Then
   If Application.Intersect(rng, PlotRange) Is Nothing Then
       On Error Resume Next
        rng.Parent.Shapes(PlotName).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
   End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 RemovePlot Target
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

I need help with Sub FixPlott. I am trying to get it to delete the Legend Entries on the Legend Key. For example if I select Main Campus and South Hall there will be blank legend entries for dunblane and greensburg. Id like the legend just to show selected buildings.

Comment: possibly best option would be to hide rows which you don't include in the chart. As a result not only legend will disappear but also 0 value series will be removed from your chart which will make it more elegant. If you need any support ask (possibly) a question in this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a corrected version of your sub:

```
Sub FixPlott(PlotName As String)
   Dim n As Long
   With ActiveSheet.Shapes(PlotName).Chart
     For n = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        With .SeriesCollection(n)
            If .Name = "" Then
               ActiveSheet.Shapes(PlotName).Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(n).Delete
            End If
        End With
     Next n
   End With
End Sub
```

I am not sure about the exact trigger you want to use. So I have included a simple string `trigger`; if the given SeriesCollection is called like `trigger`, the legend will be deleted.

Comment: Hmmm so was the simple trigger suppose to activate in the case of the name being 0. Running it and the Empty Legend Keys are still there.

Comment: This trigger idea is very simple. Explain the exact functionality you are after and I can modify the code. Also bear in mind that this condition does account for caps; I did it too simple just as an example.

Comment: We'll as you know from previously helping me that the Macro creates a graph of a fixed range. Then when you click away from the graph that it disappears. After that what I did is I added a set of CheckBoxes which allows me to toggle which buildings data I want to look at. So then I changed the fixed range from one building to a small list of them. Now what I am trying to get it to do is get rid of any blank legend keys. Could the condition be based off of the True False of the checkboxes? Or what would you suggest?

Comment: Ah! I did got your point wrong. Give me one minute and I will correct it.

Comment: If you want to remove blank labels, you don't need the trigger for anything (I thought that you want to delete the text of the labels matching some value). I have updated the code: it deletes the whole lengend when the name is blank.

Comment: Old question I know.  I have had the problem that legend entries are sometimes ordered differently to the data series, and unpredictably so, so that the wrong entry gets deleted with this approach.  Anyone else had this?  Nothing's simple in VBA....

Comment: @bazz So, you are saying that ActiveSheet.Shapes(PlotName).Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(i) some times refers to a different element than ActiveSheet.Shapes(PlotName).Chart.SeriesCollection(i)? In that case, the proposed solution wouldn't be correct and I wouldn't mind to fix it (pretty straightforward for example by comparing names or trying to rely on whatever other data source/approach). Could you please provide a sample scenario (input conditions or spreadsheet/VBA parameters) where  that problem might be reproduced?

Comment: @Bazz Are you OK? Using such an ambiguous statement (unpredictably different?!) to criticise a so old answer meant to solve a very specific problem under very specific conditions (I am not here for providing you ready-to-be-used answers and anyone with even low VBA knowledge should be able to easily adapt that code to a slightly different scenario like what you propose) sounds a bit weird. But not answering my nice reply sounds even weirder. Are you sure that you know how SO is supposed to be used (and/or how to respectfully interact with other people)? Do you have even basic VBA knowledge?

Comment: @varocarbas I didn't mean to criticise.  The answer is okay but I think sometimes fails.  I tried this approach and the wrong legend entry got deleted.  In the end I gave up and simply deleted the legend entries manually.  I'm not sure what conditions caused this behaviour and I haven't had time to look into it.  People are allowed to reply in their own timing.  Relax.

Comment: @Bazz I am very relaxed (although you comment was certainly peculiar and actually I have had quite a few weird interactions in SO with people with unclear-to-me requests, goals & expectations). Anyway, I always welcome sensible and motivated critics everywhere, much more here where the answers are expected to be generic enough or, at least, clearly state their limitations. The problem is that you are complaining about a random behaviour without even defining its conditions! How am I expected to account for it? To not mention the fact that you might be unawaredly using this code wrongly...

Comment: @Bazz ... that's why your apparent limited knowledge is relevant here too (additionally to be a kind of basic requirement for using SO answers, expected to not be ready-to-use solutions, but good indications for people in a position to use/understand them); your code might not have failed because of the approach being wrong, but because of you using it wrongly. For example, that code wouldn't recognise a name consisting in one or more blank spaces. Hopefully, you have understood everything (how to participate in SO + deal with me) properly now and we both can stop wasting time unnecessarily :)